# Copy file from one place to another using progress bar in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsprogressindicator

I want to use progress bar to show the progress while I am copying a file from one place to another. So here is the code for copying file:

```
 if([fileManager isReadableFileAtPath:sourcePath])
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:sourcePath toPath:destinationPath error:nil];
```

And here is the code for progressing bar (I use NSProgressIndicator):

```
// Set the max value to our source file size
[_localProgressIndicator setMaxValue:fileSizeTotal];
[_localProgressIndicator setDoubleValue:0.0];

//Start showing progress bar in using NSTime
if(!timerForProgressBar){
    timerForProgressBar = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05
                                                            target:self
                                                         selector:@selector(checkCopyingPorgress:)
                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:YES];
    [_localProgressIndicator startAnimation:self];
}

-(void)checkCopyingPorgress:(NSTimer *)aTimer
{
  if(fileCurrentSize >= fileSizeTotal)
  {
     fileCurrentSize = 0;
     [aTimer invalidate];
     aTimer = NULL;
     [_localProgressIndicator setDoubleValue:0.0];
     [_localProgressIndicator stopAnimation: self];
  }
  else
  {
    [_localProgressIndicator setDoubleValue: fileCurrentSize/100.0];
    [_localProgressIndicator displayIfNeeded];
  }
}
```

So my question is how to get the "fileCurrentSize" from fileManager when I am copying a file from one place to another?? Thanks !!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may use

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

and then fetch `[dictObject valueForKey@"NSFileSize"];` from the file property dictionary

Comment: How to fetch it? When I call it, it will just give me the whole file size.. instead of current.

Comment: You mean you want to know how much the new file has been copied.

Comment: Kind of. When I call NSFileSize function, it just gives me the whole size of the file. Is it possible to get current size while copying so that I can use the progress bar.

Comment: You might try the "- (unsigned long long)fileSize;" method instead. IIRC this will return what you expect while the "NSFileBusy" attribute is YES.